# Condition met, but conditional action not executed in coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a coroutine like so:

```
private IEnumerator ShortFlashes()
{
    this.startedShortFlashes = true;
    this.finishedShortFlashes = false;

    const int maxFlashes = 3;
    int numFlashesSoFar = 1;

    if (numFlashesSoFar > maxFlashes)
    {
        Debug.Log("All 3 short flashes finished!");
        this.finishedShortFlashes = true;
        yield break;
    }

    while (numFlashesSoFar <= maxFlashes)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.05f);
        this.Renderer.enabled = true;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.05f);
        this.Renderer.enabled = false;

        Debug.Log("Number of short flashes so far: " + numFlashesSoFar);

        numFlashesSoFar++;
    }
}
```

When this coroutine is running, I can see messages in the Unity console enumerating the number of short flashes, just as intended. (`Debug.Log("Number of short flashes so far: " + numFlashesSoFar);`).

However, `Debug.Log("All 3 short flashes finished!");` is never executed, even when `numFlashesSoFar` exceeds `maxFlashes`.

This is very inconvenient, because in my `Update()` method, there are some additional actions that I would like to perform if `this.finishedShortFlashes` is `true`.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why do you put that check before `while`?

Comment: @Sinatr It's like returning earlier from a function. `yield break;` is just like `return` in a `void` function but for coroutine functions. OP used this to prevent running the code in the `while` loop if `numFlashesSoFar > maxFlashes`.

Comment: @Programmer, I don't know what are *coroutine functions*. In C# method with `yield` have its body executed once, so check should never ever occurs again *while `while` loop is running*, it will only happens *once*, at the beginning, therefore my question, idk maybe couroutines works differently? If its meant to *prevent* `while` from running, then OP did a very naive mistake because condition is never true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've hardcoded the values.

```
const int maxFlashes = 3;
int numFlashesSoFar = 1;

if (numFlashesSoFar > maxFlashes)
{
    //...
}
```

`if (numFlashesSoFar > maxFlashes)` is effectively equal to `if (1 > 3)`, which is never true.

I genuinely don't understand why you structured the code the way you did, which makes it hard for me to understand the core issue here.

This makes much more sense:

```
const int maxFlashes = 3;
int numFlashesSoFar = 1;

while (numFlashesSoFar <= maxFlashes)
{
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.05f);
    this.Renderer.enabled = true;
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.05f);
    this.Renderer.enabled = false;

    Debug.Log("Number of short flashes so far: " + numFlashesSoFar);

    numFlashesSoFar++;
}

Debug.Log("All 3 short flashes finished!");
this.finishedShortFlashes = true;
```

Note that you don't need the `if`. When the `while` loop finishes, you already know that the condition is met (otherwise the `while` loop would not have finished yet.

I don't understand the purpose of the `yield break;` in your code. It seems unnecessary, so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the point of `yield` keyword.

Once the execution encounter `yield return` the execution is transferred back to the calling method and the execution state for the routine is retained. The next time you call that same routine, the execution resumes from where it has been yielded. 
More information is available in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)

In that particular case, the line `Debug.Log("All 3 short flashes finished!");` is never hit, because when the control steps into the method initially, the `numFlashesSoFar` variable is set to 1 so the condition is never met. Then it goes into the loop, where the `yield` keyword is encountered. So the next time, the execution continues from within the loop.

Comment: I think OP is (mis)using `yield` so that he can "step through" the logic in separate steps by calling `MoveNext()` on the enumerator. I have my reservations about doing so, but I do think it works for what OP expects it to do. Unless I've completely misread the intention of the code.

Comment: @Flater: Yes, I believe this is the OP intention as well. But I also think that he might not count for the behavior of the `yield`...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you put that if-statement above the loop. The while loop will continue until the while-statement is false. There is no need for the if-statement, you can simply put the code you have inside your if-statement below the loop:

```
private IEnumerator ShortFlashes()
{
    this.startedShortFlashes = true;
    this.finishedShortFlashes = false;

    const int maxFlashes = 3;
    int numFlashesSoFar = 1;

    while (numFlashesSoFar <= maxFlashes)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.05f);
        this.Renderer.enabled = true;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.05f);
        this.Renderer.enabled = false;

        Debug.Log("Number of short flashes so far: " + numFlashesSoFar);

        numFlashesSoFar++; 
    }

    Debug.Log("All 3 short flashes finished!");
    this.finishedShortFlashes = true;
}
```

Also, you can see `yield return` in a Coroutine as a "temporary break in code", because it waits for the next frame to continue the code. Unless you return a WaitForSeconds of course, then it will wait until the given amount of time has passed.